# nodejs - save output from a function to a text file

Tags: node.js, function, express, output, console.log

I have this function in nodejs that every 12500 ms it reaches out to my sql DB and pulls down the info my my table.

This is working like a charm however what I would like to add is add two more functions ..... That being ....

Number One: Spit the output of this function to a text file on my server.

Number Two: I want to remove all contents in this text file before the next time it runs i.e. I want to overwrite everything in that file each time. So each time this runs the file is empty

```
function readthedb() {
            sql.connect(config, function (err) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            var request = new sql.Request();
            if (err) throw err;
            request.query('SELECT * FROM TABLE', function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log(result[0]["BLA"])
        console.log(result[0]["BLA"])
        console.log(result[1]["BLA"])
        console.log(result[1]["BLA"])
        console.log(result[2]["BLA"])
        console.log(result[2]["BLA"])
        });
//});
});
}
```

readthedb();

setInterval(readthedb, 12500);

Answer (score 3):

Simply with the `fs` ([FileSystem](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)) module.

```
const fs = require("fs")

request.query('SELECT * FROM TABLE', function (err, result, fields) {
     fs.writeFile("result.txt", result, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('File successfully written to disk');
     })  
});
```

It write `result` to `result.txt`, overwriting its content each time.

Comment: Looks like I have a parsing issue .. It just spits 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] in to the file (head bang)

Comment: try fs.writeFile("filename.txt", JSON.stringify(result), err => {})

Comment: Correct, convert your result to a string before writing it